# UIImage overlaps labels if it's set to .scaleAspectFill

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage, swift3

My app loads images from a backend and displays them in a UITableViewCell, that contains a UIImageView to display it and some labels and buttons.

I've added the suggested contraints to the UITableViewCell with the 'Reset to suggested contraints' option.

Here's some of the code after retrieving the data:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = PostTableViewCell()

    if (self.posts.count == 0) { return cell }

    let post = posts[indexPath.row]

    // Instancia o reuse identifier
    if post["post_image"] != nil {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.PostWithImage, for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
    } else {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.PostWithoutImage, for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
    }
    return cell
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    var cell = PostTableViewCell()
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.PostWithImage) as! PostTableViewCell
    return cell.bounds.size.height;
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    var cell = PostTableViewCell()
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.PostWithImage) as! PostTableViewCell
    return cell.bounds.size.height;
}

private func configureCell(cell: PostTableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {

    cell.queue.cancelAllOperations()

    let operation: BlockOperation = BlockOperation()
    operation.addExecutionBlock { [weak operation] () -> Void in

        DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: { [weak operation] () -> Void in
            if (operation?.isCancelled)! { return }

            let post = self.posts[indexPath.row]
            cell.accessibilityIdentifier = post.recordID.recordName

            guard let postTitle = post["post_title"], let postBody = post["post_body"] else {
                return
            }

            if let asset = post["post_image"] as? CKAsset {

                self.imageCache.queryDiskCache(forKey: post.recordID.recordName, done: { (image, cachetype) in
                    if image != nil {
                        cell.postImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                        cell.postImageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleBottomMargin,
                                                               .flexibleHeight,
                                                               .flexibleLeftMargin,
                                                               .flexibleRightMargin,
                                                               .flexibleTopMargin,
                                                               .flexibleWidth ];
                        cell.postImageView.image = image!
                    } else {
                        do {
                            let data = try Data(contentsOf: asset.fileURL)
                            let image = UIImage(data: data)
                            cell.postImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                            cell.postImageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleBottomMargin,
                                                                   .flexibleHeight,
                                                                   .flexibleLeftMargin,
                                                                   .flexibleRightMargin,
                                                                   .flexibleTopMargin,
                                                                   .flexibleWidth ];
                            cell.postImageView.image = image!
                            self.imageCache.store(image!, forKey: post.recordID.recordName)

                        } catch {
                            print("Error 1001 = \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                    }
                })

            }

            cell.titleLabel.text = postTitle as? String
            cell.bodyLabel.text =  postBody as? String
        })
    }
    cell.queue.addOperation(operation)
}
```

[Here's](https://imgur.com/a/X88vg) some prints from the app itself that shows the image overlapping over the labels.

It only overlaps if the image is in portrait mode, if the image was taken in landscape it suits well.

What's the best way to bypass this issue?

Comment: If it's not set to .scaleAspectFill it doesn't overlap the labels but it doesn't fit properly

Comment: Did you set your imageView's clipsToBounds = true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can programmatically tell the image to draw only in the given image area. If your constraints are working properly and it is staying the correct size, the image *may* just be drawing beyond the View bounds because of the .scaleAscpedtFill setting.

Do this by using .clipToBounds = true.

```
cell.postImageView.clipToBounds = true
```

Or, you can set it in interface builder as well, per the image below.

[image: Enable Clip To Bounds]

Give that a try and see if that helps?

Comment: Hmm. Let me try and I'll feedback inm

Comment: Well, gotta tell you that solved my issue. Thank you so much Brian.